# Python OSGEO/GDAL ST_Intersection error

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

I am trying to implement the answer to this question:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119374/intersect-shapefiles-using-shapely

but i get the error:

RuntimeError: Undefined function 'ST_Intersection' used.

Here is the code. It crashes on the layer = ogr_ds.ExecuteSQL(SQL, dialect='SQLITE') line. I tried updating the GDAL library but I am running into a pip vcvarsall.bat issue (Also very frustrating). Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
from osgeo import ogr
ogr.UseExceptions()
ogr_ds = ogr.Open(r'D:\inputs', True) 
SQL = """\
SELECT ST_Intersection(A.geometry, B.geometry) AS geometry, A.*, B.*
FROM stops A, zones B
WHERE ST_Intersects(A.geometry, B.geometry);
"""
layer = ogr_ds.ExecuteSQL(SQL, dialect='SQLITE')
# copy result back to datasource as a new shapefile
layer2 = ogr_ds.CopyLayer(layer, 'result')
# save, close
layer = layer2 = ogr_ds = None
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error arises because you need your SQLite driver to be compiled with SQLite SQL dialect. See: [Link](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html)

As for updating and compiling gdal, that can be annoying. What operating system are you running?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).